# Most effective way of drawing 4 lines in an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone

basic question, but I'm unsure. Not looking for code as an answer.

I want to draw 4 short lines 1px lines on a view. What is the best way to approach this task? Options:-

- Load an image of the line, then create 4 UIImageViews with it.
- Create my own subclass of a UIView that draws a line in the draw rect method.
- Draw elsewhere on another view, another UIImageView that has an UIImage inside it (is this possible?)
- Another way?

Thanks
Ross

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way is to create a `UIView` subclass and perform your drawing in `drawRect:`. See the [CoreGraphics guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html) for details on how to draw a line.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty way to achieve this is to just create a UIView and set it's height (or width, depending on its orientation) to 1px, and then set a background colour and slap it onto your view as a subview.

Comment: nice. I know really this doesn't matter, but for science's sake: will it just require as much resources as using `drawRect:`?

Comment: Draw rect may be more efficient, I don't know really. I imagine that a 1px high view with a black background would consume the same amount of processing as a view that drew a 1px black line. Though depending on the view, if it was 10px high and draw the line in the center, and the rest of the view was white, I imagine that would take more processing since there's a bigger area to draw. Again, I'm just guessing.

Comment: Each view has a fixed rendering cost and additional costs in relation to the size/transform/other properties. If you only have one line, the single view with 1px height or width will likely be quicker, but at some point multiple lines in a single view will outpace it.  If performance becomes an issue, profile to see which works best